# HttpClient.PostAsync Image upload

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

Not sure what is wrong with this code.  I get a generic "An error occurred while sending the request".  Here is the C# code:

```
string t1 = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.je.EE/files/Pictures/Observations/";
string t2 = "592018 115019 AM.jpg";
string t3 = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.je.EE/files/Pictures/Observations/592018 115019 AM.jpg";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

// var imageContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream("my_path.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
var imageContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(t3, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));

imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
// content.Add(imageContent, "image", "image.jpg");
content.Add(imageContent, "image", t2);

var url = "http://localhost:62810/api/Files/Upload";
await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: don't use localhost.  Use the IP or FQDN instead.  And look at the InnerException to get more detail about the failure

Comment: I am using localhost for testing. Is that a problem?  How can I see the InnerException.  I will google it also

Comment: Yes, localhost is a problem.  There are ways around it with Android but generally its just a good idea to avoid it in the first place.  The InnerException is a property on the Exception object - use the debugger to see it's value

Comment: OK about localhost - thank you.  Is it easy to get around this with Android - which is what I am working on? How?

Comment: Here is the InnerException: {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <bcdc1df2b3724ab69797f3819a126346>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in <bcdc1df2b3724ab69797f3819a126346>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: it's much easier to just use the IP.  The exception is clearly saying it can't connect to the server, which makes sense because you're using localhost

Comment: Thank you & understand.  I will work on using the IP.

Comment: @PizzaBoatJim Use 10.0.2.2 as the IP address of the "Host" (the PC that is running the Android emulator). This is a specially mapped IP address that the emulator can use to connect to its hosting environment